# Differentiate between memory leak and NULL dereferencing

Tags: operating-system

I don't understand the difference between memory leak and null dereferencing. How are these two terms related?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are many references to these terms on stack overflow and in general on the internet. Please clarify your question to include what you understand and don't understand about each term, possibly including sources. Not only does this show you have made a fair attempt at solving the problem yourself, it helps us help you resolve the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operating-system have a memory map for each process (each executable you start like the one you compile and run). This memory map tells the OS what pages of physical memory are allocated to the process. A memory leak is when you allocate memory using the `new` operator in C++ (or malloc() in C) but never release it later. The actual memory leak happens when you change the address that a pointer points to when it has been allocated with `new` without releasing memory first with `delete`.

There are 2 types of memory allocation. One is static the other is dynamic. Static memory allocation works like the following:

```
unsigned char memory[10];
```

In this example, I allocate 10 unsigned chars statically. This means that the memory will be allocated in the executable at compilation time. The executable will contain space for these unsigned chars I allocated statically. When you will launch the executable, the OS will place the content of that array in RAM (after loading the executable from disk). In this example, `memory` represents a pointer to the first element of the unsigned char array.

Dynamic memory works like the following (in C++):

```
unsigned char* memory = new unsigned char[10];
```

In this example, I allocate 10 unsigned chars on the heap instead of statically in the executable. The heap is managed by the OS and grows according to how much memory you allocate. There is no limit to memory allocation with `new`. Nothing prevents a program from allocating the whole RAM. If a program runs for a long time and it has memory leaks, it could allocate a lot of RAM until the OS starts having a hard time to make it work with the rest of the system (or until the amount of memory allocated to the process is bigger than RAM).

This works by doing a system call in the OS. When you compile a program which has the above dynamic memory allocation, you compile the line to a system call in the kernel to ask for memory. This is OS specific so the program you compile will have to be recompiled to work on a different OS.

In the meantime, you can create a nullptr or initialize a pointer to 0 like the following:

```
unsigned char* ptr = nullptr;
or
unsigned char* ptr = 0;
```

When you dereference that pointer, the dereference will be compiled to a memory fetch. The memory fetch will trigger a page fault because the memory at 0 wasn't allocated to your process. Then the OS will look in it's memory map for the process. It will determine that this address access wasn't legal and kill the process.

The terms are pretty much different and there isn't much relation between the 2.